# Align the columns of thead with tbody

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, display

There is a table without any settings for `<thead>` and `<tbody>`. And it looks like this:

I had to make the table scrollable, so in this case I added to `<tbody>` this styling:

```
display: block;
height: 475px;
overflow: scroll;
```

Now, `<tbody>` has a height of 475px and it's scrollable. This problem was solved!

But now `<thead>` doesn't look right:

To solve this problem, I added to `<thead>`:

```
display: table;
```

Now it looks better:

But still, the column headers are not aligned to the columns.

How can be this solved and make the table looks like it was looking before adding the scrolling part?

Comment: can you please create a [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or share a link to the code

Answer (score 0):

You can make this basically by setting thead and tbody display as block, and setting a fixed width to both th and td tags.

```css
table {
    background: steelblue
}

thead, tbody {
    display: block;
}

tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100px;
}
 
thead th:nth-child(1), tbody td:nth-child(1) {
   background: pink;
   width: 90px;
   word-break: break-all;
}

thead th:nth-child(2), tbody td:nth-child(2) {
   background: olive;
   width: 140px;
   word-break: break-all;
}

thead th:nth-child(3), tbody td:nth-child(3) {
   background: tomato;
   width: 80px;
   word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Make Payment</th>
      <th>Order Number</th>
      <th>Order Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>V</td>
      <td>9598959</td>
      <td>2020-05-12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Inserting a long text here just to show it breaks</td>
      <td>9598959</td>
      <td>2020-05-12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>V</td>
      <td>9598959</td>
      <td>2020-05-12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>V</td>
      <td>9598959</td>
      <td>2020-05-12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>V</td>
      <td>9598959</td>
      <td>2020-05-12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>V</td>
      <td>9598959</td>
      <td>2020-05-12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>V</td>
      <td>9598959</td>
      <td>2020-05-12</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but I'm not sure it solves my problem... this is how my table should look like: https://i.imgur.com/FriUOP7.png, I guess that a fixed width for th and td won't solve the problem. Is there a way to make it work based on how much text is in that field?

Comment: Another approach, still using the snippet I sent before, is adding this css: ` thead th:nth-child(1), tbody td:nth-child(1) { width: 80px, word-break: break-all } ` , and so on to each column you want to resize, just by setting up the column number inside: nth-child(column number) and the width to that column, based on the text length width you want to follow (I edited my answer so you can run the snippet). I hope this helps you.